# Zurb Foundation Abide password matching

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, haml, abide

I am trying to match passwords using Zurb foundation abide, everything works fine except for the `data-equalto` tag, my code is:

```
 .password-field
        %label
          Parola
          %small necesar
        %input#pw1{required: '', type: 'password'}
        %small.error A strong password is needed
      .password-field
        %label
          Confirma Parola
          %small necesar
        %input{required: '', type: 'password' , "data-equalto"=> 'pw1'}
        %small.error A strong password is needed or passwords do not match
```

I am expecting for the  `A strong password is needed or passwords do not match` message to pop but it's not happening

Answer (score 0):

The password validation pattern was removed presumably because there are varying opinions on what makes a password "strong enough."

You can define your own password field requirements however.  See the [abide docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html).

```
$(document).foundation({
  abide : {
    patterns: {
      password: /^yourRegexHere/
    }
  }
});
```